# Is there a notepad++ with github plugin?

Tags: version-control, github, notepad++

I see that there is a subversion plugin for npp, but I didn't see anything similar for github. I want to be able to type the commit messages straight in notepad++ editor rather than git command line.

Is there one?

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin for http://github.com (the web site), or [Git](http://git-scm.com) (the revision control system) itself?

Comment: The later.  Although the former might be interesting as well.  Thanks

Comment: http://forum.lowyat.net/topic/1358320/all

Comment: There's [NPPGit](https://github.com/alansbraga/NPPGit) nowadays, but it hasn't been mainained or developed much. It's also rather basic in what it offers, compared e..g. to what git support ships with VSCode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git is generally designed to be fairly independent of editor.

If you're working on Windows, have you considered [msysgit](https://msysgit.github.io/)?

There's also a [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org), if you're familiar with TortoiseSVN.

Comment: I think the question is about a git plugin for Notepad++, I have been using such plugin. Obviously a git is required before install this plugin.

Comment: Integration like showing modified lines, keyboard shortcut add/commit/push is what is meant by plugin. Switching to a terminal for those is simple, but slow in comparison.

Answer (score 10):

There is a Git plugin for Notepad++, but it seems designed to work in conjunction with TortoiseGit: http://forum.lowyat.net/topic/1358320/all

Answer (score 10):

This is a really old question, but I just bumped into it today and thought I'd share my strategy (second path asked for by the OP), as I can't seem to be able to find a ***convenient*** plugin for making Notepad++ and GitHub work together.

You can use [GitHub Desktop App](https://desktop.github.com/) to set you repository locally, make commits, pulls, pushes, etc. Just login with your account, and then create a local repository for your project. As you can see in the referenced page, an added benefit to this approach is that the application provides a rich set of features, difficult to match by a plugin.

After creating the repository, just open the files you wish to edit with Notepad++. Make some changes, save and use the GitHub Desktop Application to do all GitHub related stuff.

By the way, if you have two monitors, or a big one, you can just have the two applications open side by side, which emulates similar setups you can find in advanced IDEs (Eclipse, for example). I find this to be even more convenient and fluid than having to open a separate plugin dialogue for doing my Git related stuff. The GitHub Desktop application will even refresh automatically, without any interaction being required from you, after you make any editions to the files (using Notepadd++) or any changes in the file structure (add, rename, move, delete files).

Comment: Good answer. I am trying to do the same using the "_GitHub Desktop_" "_Electron_"-based App and "_GitHub_"'s "_Atom.io_" Editor. They should be running smoothly, but for the moment (versions 0.8.2 x64 / 1.19.7 x64 respectively) they do not seem even to be able to communicate with each other due to some bugs. Also, they are very big (200 MB RAM for the "_Atom.io_" Editor App completely empty) and they are loading very slowly. I think that the "_Eclipse_" "_Oxygen_" I.D.E. is a better solution.

Comment: @user4524350 Eclipse is never a better solution. You need to decide whether you want a text editor or an IDE and then choose between them